# Angular blogs details page not displaying any data until I refresh the page

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular and trying to write a small blog but I got stuck.
I have a component called **home**. This is where I display all the data I got from my API using `*ngFor`. In the `home.component.html`, I have the following line of code

`<button class="btn post-btn" [routerLink] = "['/detail', blog.slug]">Read More &nbsp; <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>`

When I click on this button it takes me to another component called **details**. This is where I display the information about the blog post that was clicked.

My problem now is that `detail.component.html` doesn't display the information from my `detail.component.ts` until I refresh the page. How can I go about this please?

In my `service.ts` file, I have the following code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http"
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HomeServiceService {

  url:string = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/'

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getBlogs(){
    return this.http.get(this.url, {
      headers: {
        accept: "application/json",
      }
    })
  }

  getPosts():Observable<any[]>{
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.url);
  }

  getBlogDetails(blogSlug) {
    return this.http.get(this.url + blogSlug);
  }
}
```

My `detail.component.ts` file is below

```
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit {

  item:any = []
  
  constructor(private data: HomeServiceService, private _route: ActivatedRoute,) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getBlogDetails(this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('blogSlug'));
  }

  getBlogDetails(blogSlug) {
    this.data.getBlogDetails(blogSlug).subscribe(res => {
      this.item = res;
      this.item = this.item.data;
      console.log(this.item);
      
    });
  }
}
```

I have these lines in my app.routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'detail/:blogSlug', component: DetailComponent },
];
```

Below is part of my detail.component.html

```
<main>
    <section class="container">
        <div class="site-content">
            <div class="posts">
                <div class="post-content" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="200">
                    <div class="post-image">
                        <div>
                            <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000{{item.thumbnail}}" class="img" alt="{{item.title}}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="post-info flex-row">
                            <span><i class="fas fa-user text-gray"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Admin</span>
                            <!-- <span><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt text-gray"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;January 14, 2022</span> -->
                            <span><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt text-gray"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{item.uploaded_date | date}}</span>
                            <span>2 Commets</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-title">
                        <a href="#">{{item.title}}</a>
                        <p [innerHTML]="item.review"></p>
                        <a href="{{downloadEndPoint}}{{item.slug}}/{{item.id}}/" download="{{item.title}}"><button class="btn post-btn">Click To Download&nbsp; <i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i></button></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>                
            </div>
```

In my `app.component.html`, I have the following code

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Comment: Can you please share additional details/code for your html pages and service file? It will help me to re-create a local project and troubleshoot.

Comment: What does your router look like? Perhaps you can share Stackblitz reproduction of the issue.

Comment: I have edited the question to include more details. @HarshSingla

Comment: I suggest to move "getBlogDetails" method in ngOnInit() method and check.
Please keep me informed.

Comment: Are you getting any devtools console errors after clicking on the _Read More_ button? Also, where are you inserting the `<router-outlet>` element? Please also share that code, because that will define where exactly the `DetailComponent` is shown.

Comment: I have added the `getBlogDetails` method in `ngOnInit()` but the issue persists. If I inspect the page I won't see any error in the console and if I check the html element, it contains all the data. I have also added my `app.component.html` in the question. @HarshSingla

Comment: @Sammy - I was not able to replicate this issue. I tried to duplicate the flow but it is working as expected for me.

sample project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fi7oce?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fdetail%2Fdetail.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fdetail%2Fdetail.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts

Comment: @HarshSingla - I know you might be too busy but can you spare some time for me for a live session? Please sir

Answer (score 0):

firstly when you navigate from home, debug and make sure the slug is being gotten from the URL, if that is working you can try converting your getBlogDetails() an observable just like getPosts() and then subscribe to it in your details.component.ts

also you can share a stackblitz link for better debugging.

Comment: The slug is being gotten from the url. That is what I'm passing to `getBlogDetails`. I've also tried making the `getBlogDetails` an observable but it didn't work. If I inspect the page, I'll see that all data is in the html but the page won't display appropriately until I refresh the page

Comment: okay check if your importing the right modules, i.e DetailsComponentModule is beign imported in app.module.ts